# Format currency input field with dollar sign & commas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, formatting

I have a revenue input field in a javascript/jquery form:

1. Need a dollar sign :before
2. add commas as the currency increases

I have a dollar sign showing via css, but issues centering it and ensuring the field entry point is next to it without overlapping. Unsure how to do the commas. Any suggestions or tips are welcome!

HTML:

```
  <form id="rev-calculator">
  <label for="price">Monthly Revenue</label>
  <div class="fields">
    <input type="number" name="price" id="price" min="0" max="10000000000" required data-type="number"> </input>
    <br>
  </form>
```

CSS:

```
  <style>
      .body {
        text-align: left;
      }
      
      .fields {
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
      }
      
      .fields:before {
        content: "$";
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        left:30px;
      }
      
      #price {
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 15px;
        padding: 10px;
        color: black;
      }
    </style>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  $('#rev-calculator').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var price = $("#price").val();
    console.log(price);
  })
</script>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/kedarPE/pen/JjroYyb

[input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57xnu.png)

Comment: The browser decides how to render the number input, you cant add text such as commas to it. And what's wrong with the dollar sign?

Comment: Maybe see this for comma workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681785/html-number-input-not-allowing-javascript-to-display-commas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well here's a way, though in truth not as simple as I hoped when I started down this path. You can use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) to get the comma in there (according to locale). To accomodate decimals, I sniff for them in the beginning and append them to the result.

To allow for the comma, I made this a text field with a pattern attribute. Also, I adjusted your CSS to make it a little nicer looking with the $

```js
$('#price').keydown(function(e) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let parts = $(this).val().split(".");
    let v = parts[0].replace(/\D/g, ""),
      dec = parts[1]
    let calc_num = Number((dec !== undefined ? v + "." + dec : v));
    // use this for numeric calculations
    // console.log('number for calculations: ', calc_num);
    let n = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN').format(v);
    n = dec !== undefined ? n + "." + dec : n;
    $(this).val(n);
  })
})
```

```css
.body {
  text-align: left;
}

.fields {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.fields:before {
  content: "$";
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
}

#price {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="rev-calculator">
  <label for="price">Monthly Revenue</label>
  <div class="fields">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9.,]+" name="price" id="price" required data-type="number" />
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Only issue now is that commas mess with my calculations. have to find a way for it to strip the commas out before running the operations, if you know of anything lmk!

Comment: @Kedar - check out the revised answer, I put that in there for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised the unique answer for this issue has a lot of votes because it has a tiny but major flaw: the event shouldn't be keydown, it should be keyup. If you use keydown, it won't read the keys you are pressing at the moment but the previous one. So, please update your answer.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31363028)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to @Kinglish's answer, here's an improved version of the code.

```js
document.querySelector('#price').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  const parts = e.target.value.split('.');
  const value = parts[0].replace(/\D/g, '');
  const decimal = parts[1];

  let newValue = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-EN').format(value);

  // Prevent non-numeric decimal
  if (!isNaN(decimal)) {
    newValue = `${newValue}.${decimal}`;
  }

  // Prevent placing 0 when empty
  e.target.value =
    value === '' && newValue === '0' ? '' : newValue;
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="price" placeholder="Price" />
```