# Format currency input field with commas in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const valueRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
const CurrencyInput = () => {
    const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
    return (
      <>
          <CurrencyContainer
            onClick={() => valueRef.current?.focus()}
            isFocused={focus}
          >
            <CurrencyInput
              type="number"
              value={storage.updatesomevalue}
              onChange={e => dispatch(updatesomevalue(parseInt(e.target.value)))}
              ref={valueRef}
              onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
              onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
            />
            <Currency>USD</Currency>
          </CurrencyContainer>
      </>
    );
  };
```

`<CurrencyContainer>` is a styled div, `CurrencyInput` is a styled input, and `<Currency>` is a styled p.

I found the perfect behavior I'm looking for within this question here (I don't need the dollar sign) but haven't been able to integrate it within my existing code. [Format currency input field with dollar sign & commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175939/format-currency-input-field-with-dollar-sign-commas)

Could someone please help me implement this within my typescript react function?

Edit: A lot of people have asked what I'm trying to do ... I'm trying to make sure the numbers into the currency input are comma separated for visibility. I want 1000000 to be visible as 1,000,000.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate it within my existing code"? The format of values in an `input type="number"` is not changeable from code so that's a nonstarter. You're using `parseInt` in your `onChange` handler, so that precludes decimals... How about you try something, showing what you tried, what research you did to get where you got to, then we can help from there.

Comment: I don't understand ... so if I remove type="number" and add that function to the onchange handler, it'll work? is it possible to have commas only on the frontend, but make sure commas aren't sent to the backend? sending it as a number is important afaik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was nice that you added some of your code.  It might be helpful to you and others if you include some attempt at what you are trying to do.

I haven't tested it very much, but the idea here is that the input is now a "text" input with a pattern filter.   Any keypress is dispatched to the `useReducer` function -- which takes the string representation of the user's input and breaks it into the whole and fractional values (if there's a decimal point) - then we strip commas, and ensure that the decimal value isn't more than two numbers.

I modified your components to just a div and input - so you'll need to fix that up.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const CurrencyInput = () => {
  const valueRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const [value, dispatchValue] = React.useReducer(
    (state: string, newValue: string) => {
      const [formattedWholeValue, decimalValue = "0"] = newValue.split(".");
      const significantValue = formattedWholeValue.replace(/,/g, "");
      const floatValue = parseFloat(
        significantValue + "." + decimalValue.slice(0, 2)
      );
      if (isNaN(floatValue) === false) {

        // you can dispatch to your redux store here - floatValue should be 
        // a number, that's well formed

        let n = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-EN", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 0,
          maximumFractionDigits: 2
        }).format(floatValue);

        if (newValue.includes(".") && !n.includes(".")) {
          return n + ".";
        }
        return n;
      }
      return "0";
    },
    ""
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={() => valueRef.current?.focus()} isFocused={focus}>
        <input
          type="text"
          pattern="d+(.d{2})?"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => dispatchValue(e.target.value)}
          ref={valueRef}
          onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
          onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
        />
        <div>USD</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CurrencyInput />
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Oh - you need to reset your redux store if returning "0" as well --- it means there was some kind of problem converting the input into a float number.   (isNaN)

Comment: do you have a codepen by any chance? if not I can test this out tomorrow! thanks for answering!

Comment: also I've edited my question so the end goal is more clear!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-silence-93iesf?file=/src/App.tsx